# Run 4.0 .NET dll on asp page in web running 3.5 framework (2.0 app pool)

Tags: .net, asp-classic

There's a number of pages about running .NET dlls on asp pages, and a number on running dlls on sites with differing frameworks, but none of the solutions are quite the combination I need, requiring a new iteration of a similar question

I have an ASP page on which I need to run a dll (the dll will call a service and return some values). The dll was written in Visual Studio 2013, set to run using framework 3.5.  The website is using the 2.0 app pool, and the NET pages on it are also written in 3.5.

The most streamlined solution I found that seemed to achieve my goal is here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12408/Call-a-NET-component-from-an-ASP-Page

The dll runs fine locally in debug, using both a console app and a website (both set for framework 3.5)

Trying on run the app on the intended server, it fails.  Running on the web using the 2.0 app pool, I get error 800a01ad - ActiveX component can't create object.

If I set up a test web site running the 4.0 app pool, the page and the dll run properly.  If I switch said site to the 2.0 app pool, it fails.

Sadly, switching the main website to the 4.0 app pool is not an option - way too much regression testing.

dll registered with regasm and gacutil - Iv'e tried using both the 2.0 and 4.0 versions of each, as well as housing the dll in a directory within  and out of the website's folders.  None affect the success of the test site, or the failure of the main site.

Signs point to the dll needing data from some other file or dll that isn't available on a 2.0 app pool site, but I've no idea what it could be.  The site is accessing a service at another location and uses channel factory functionality, if that's helpful.

What flummoxes me is the dll should be getting accessed via COM, so it should be running stand-alone, no?

Not sure if there's anything in the web.config that could be fouling it up on the main site, but the one for the test site is fairly nondescript

More information can be provided as needs must.

Comment: Did you run the regasm with the /codebase and /tlb parameters as in the linked article?  You have to run regasm on your wrapper class, but use gacutil on the DLL's your wrapper class calls.

Comment: I've run both  I even tried running the 2.0 version of said programs, thinking the later ones might not talk well to the 2.0 framework.

Here's the thing tho - unless I misread something horribly, in this version of the solution there only one dll that handles the wrapping as well as the 4.0 code.  So I've run regasm and gacutil on the one dll.  The sample code has only one class file.

If there's a version of the solution that uses separate dlls, that might work better - suggestions?